# Extending a Spreadsheet with SAP Netweaver Recording and Playback

Tags: automation, sap-gui

My question is regarding the "SAP GUI Script Recording and Playback" in SAP NetWeaver. The screenshot shows the three options for saving a file with the "SAP Script Recording and Playback".

[image]

One of the options is to "Extend", but when I test it, the spreadsheet is replaced with the new data every time. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Is there a way that I can have SAP add more data on to the end of a spreadsheet with the "SAP GUI Script Recording and Playback"?

EDIT: List of File Formats

The screenshot below shows the list of available File Formats.
[image]

Comment: Can you choose format for this dialog? Try "unconverted" or "tab-delimited"

Comment: @ Suncatcher: I normally choose Excel (in Office 2007 XLSX Format). I tried all of the other formats available, but they also did not "Append Data to Existing File". OpenOffice is not an option for my organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use not [Export to spreadsheet](http://fmis.minfin.bg/help/EN/66/79ad48157f11d2953700a0c930328a/frameset.htm) function but [Local file](http://help.innowera.net/PR2008/2.00/index.htm?how-to-save-alv-grid-output-to-a-excellocal-file.htm) instead.
Exporting to spreadsheet has a number of limitations, e.g. number of rows and columns (note [700206](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/700206)), filesize (note [1854956](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1854956)) and many many others.

Choose **unconverted** format or **spreadsheet** format ([was renamed](http://www.erpgreat.com/general/spreadsheet-option-is-missing-after-ehp7-upgrade.htm) to **text with tabs** after EHP7). *Spreadsheet* is tab-delimited text in fact, but it is consumed by Excel like a charm, so you can convert it to spreadsheet easily yourself.

Comment: Hi Suncather. thanks for you help. I have tried to go to System>List>Save, but all of the options are greyed out. I am not sure, but I think I need to do something else here.

Comment: I am missing the authorization to save a local file at this time. I'll try to track someone down who can give me access so that I can test this again.

Comment: yeah, you need `S_GUI` authorization object, 60 and 61 activities

Comment: @ Suncatcher, with your help I was able to get these functionalities in a different SAP landscape and as such, I will go ahead and give you the green checkmark and vote up your answer. I am putting a note for myself and everyone else here that the header information is included each time the report is "Extended" in the SAP Script Recording and Playback. Thanks again!